# Music in Flash player stops when I switch to a terminal

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, flash

I am using Xubuntu 16.04. I have observed some weird behavior. I don't know if it stems from flash player though. Only relevant thing with it can be flash player.

I opened up the browser (firefox) and went to radiotunes.com and picked a station to listen. It complained about flashplayer. I have installed the flash player by doing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplayer-installer
```

After that, I could listen to music. But this time, while I was listening to music from radiotunes, I have opened up the Guake terminal by pressing F12. The player stopped. I have tried with the default xfce terminal, it stopped again. I had to refresh the web page in order to make the music continue.

This thing doesn't only apply opening a new terminal instance, but also, if there is a terminal running and when I switch to it by doing ALT+TAB, the player stops again.

Could someone explain what is going on?

EDIT #1
This doesn't happen on youtube, which doesn't require flash player.

Comment: I have edited question.

Comment: Then can you please install the [adobe-flashplugin](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) package from Canonical Partner. This is a long shot; it ought to work the same way as `flashplugin-installer` (which btw will be uninstalled when you install `adobe-flashplugin`).